# Why is my charge blade's shield glowing?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

I started playing Monster Hunter 4 Ultimate recently. Being a primarily sword & shield user in previous iterations, I wanted to give the Charge Blade a try, as it seems to get most of the benefits of the S&S and add in a better source of damage with axe mode.

I understand the basic concepts of using the Charge Blade; charging phials in S&S and expending them in axe mode. However, on one hunt (probably due to some accidental button press), my shield started glowing red. Why/how did this happen? Are there any differences to fighting with and without this effect, damage-wise or in combo progressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With certain moves (like the burst cancel), you dump your phial energy into the shield. This increases your shield's defensive power and your axe's offensive power. Your shield will now guard like a Lance, mitigating *all* damage instead of a portion and your axe burst attacks will deal more damage. Also, any guard points you connect with will also deal burst damage to the monster.

This shield charge only lasts for a duration, so remember to keep it charged as you become more effective with it up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A couple of questions... what is the initial duration of the shield charge? Is it dependent on how many phials you have when you do it? Also, does charging phials while the shield charge is up extend the duration (is it possible to constantly stay in shield charge)?

Comment: @king14nyr Each phial you put into it is worth 30 seconds, up to a maximum of 5 minutes (10 phials). And yes, you can charge it up some more while it's already red, up to the maximum. When the shield is yellow, that means you've only got 30 seconds left.